# Find Next row and Previous Row based on result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, row, lag, lead

In this sample table fruits, I want to get previous row, current row and next row where high_low_adjstmnt < 0.

```
Table

id  name    low high    high_low_adjstmnt      volume
1   Apple   5   3         -2                   1000
2   Orange  6   9          3                   2000
3   Banana  13  17         4                   3000
4   Avocado 11  19         8                   4000
5   Berry   21  17        -4                   5000
6   Peach   7   9          2                   6000
7   Mango   9   14         5                   7000
8   Grape   18  11         7                   8000
9   Kiwi    14  13        -1                   9000
```

Desired output Result

```
id  name    low high    high_low_adjstmnt      volume
1   Apple   5   3         -2                   1000
2   Orange  6   9          3                   2000
4   Avocado 11  19         8                   4000
5   Berry   21  17        -4                   5000
6   Peach   7   9          2                   6000
8   Grape   18  11         7                   8000
9   Kiwi    14  13        -1                   9000
```

How could I get this result in query?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain the logic more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few ways to approach this. Perhaps, you can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions to get the previous and next row value then use `cte` (or derived table) to filter them like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
       LAG(high_low_adjstmnt) OVER (ORDER BY id) PreviousRow,
       LEAD(high_low_adjstmnt) OVER (ORDER BY id) NextRow
   FROM Table1)

SELECT * 
  FROM cte
WHERE (high_low_adjstmnt < 0 
         OR PreviousRow < 0
         OR NextRow < 0);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cu902HbH)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `self-join` to get previous, current and next rows using the condition `t.id = t2.id - 1 or t.id = t2.id or t.id = t2.id + 1`.

```
select t2.*
from mytable t
inner join mytable t2 on t.id = t2.id - 1 or t.id = t2.id or t.id = t2.id + 1
where t.high_low_adjstmnt < 0
```

Result :

```
id  name    low high    high_low_adjstmnt   volume
1   Apple   5   3   -2  1000
2   Orange  6   9   3   2000
4   Avocado 11  19  8   4000
5   Berry   21  17  -4  5000
6   Peach   7   9   2   6000
8   Grape   18  11  7   8000
9   Kiwi    14  13  -1  9000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vix45b_U)